numerapi python crypto signals submission
looking for a way to automate submission for Numerai crypto signals tournament. For some reason, this code (from their documentation) does not work (invalid model error, checked model id). So, if you have a working example of submitting prediction with python, or with their CLI, could you please share it?
Tried this:
import pandas as pd
from numerapi import SignalsAPI
import sys

# Check command line arguments for model ID and predictions file path
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Usage: python submit_signals.py <predictions_file_path>")
    sys.exit(1)

predictions_file_path = sys.argv[1]

# Initialize the SignalsAPI with your API key
api = SignalsAPI("key1", "key2")

try:
   
    model_id = uuid
    
    # Upload predictions from the specified file
    api.upload_predictions(predictions_file_path, model_id=model_id)

    print(f"Predictions uploaded successfully for model ID: {model_id}")

except Exception as e:
    # Print detailed error message and traceback
    print(f"An error occurred while uploading predictions: {e}")
    traceback.print_exc() 


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

For future reference: here is a script to automate numerai crypto signals uploads that actually works: https://github.com/roverbird/numerai-crypto-helper/blob/main/submit.py
